# LaTex tblr sizing the table header row

Tags: latex

I'm using the following LaTeX source to create my table. The table looks fine except for the table header row. The height of the table header row is larger than it has to be. Is there a way I can size that? I don't seem to be putting any sizing information for the table header row.

Thanks for any/all help,

Russ

```
\begin{longtblr}[
   caption = {Severity Categories}
]{ 
  rows={ rowsep=9pt }, 
  row{1}={gray!10}, 
  rowhead = 1, %repeat the first row (the header) for each time the table breaks a page
  colspec={
    |Q[c,m,wd=1.0in]|Q[l,m,wd=6.0in]|}
}
  \hline
  \begin{center} \textbf{Severity} \end{center} & %
  \begin{center} \textbf{Description} \end{center} \\ %
  \hline
```

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre], including all the necessary packages etc.